# applicationContext object in JSP

Tags: spring

How to configure in my spring project to retrieve the applicationContext object in jsp using JSTL.

Answer (score 13):

```
<%@page import="org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext"%>
<%@page import="org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils"%>
<%
  WebApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils
        .getWebApplicationContext(application);
%>
```

`application` is the JSP defined ServletContext.

If you want to retrieve a bean and use JSTL, you can then do something like:

```
<%pageContext.setAttribute("bean", context.getBean("myBean"));%>
<c:out value="${bean.property}"/>
```

But, just because you can, doesn't mean you should. If you are doing anything more than displaying a bean's property you probably want to put this in a Servlet or some other controller.

Also, you *do not* want to be using the ApplicationContext as a way to pass beans between your controllers and views.

Comment: I want to retrieve applicationContext object by jstl like${applicationContext...}.Is there any way do this.

Comment: This is better because it only needs spring-web not spring-webmvc

Answer (score 5):

Spring root web application context is available in servlet context attribute named:  `org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT`:

```
${applicationScope['org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT']}
```

Haven't tried it, but should be accessible via JSTL. But what you want to achieve? Is JSP really a good place to fetch beans manually and perform some business operations? Shouldn't you do all the work in servlet/controller and let JSP do only the view, as it was intended?

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz
: I am not trying to get beans in my jsp doing business oprions,but i am trying to get spring collection element using application context in my jsp.Please let me know,if you have any piece of code.

Comment: OK, but can't you add this collection to request/session attributes in servlet/controller and then access them easily using JSTL? Seems much cleaner...

Comment: this is meta data.As per my requirement i have to access like this.

Comment: So please try the `${applicationScope...}` syntax above and let us know if it works.

Comment: @raj: I've tried it and it works for me. What happens when you try it? (exception, empty result, not parsed result...)

Comment: @Sinuhe:I am getting applicationcontext as null.

Comment: Can you try running `application.getAttribute("org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT");` in scriptlet and in some servlet to see whether the Spring context is there? What does `org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext()` return?

Comment: @ Tomasz Nurkiewicz:I will try this and let you know.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** I was worng, it doesn't work. Anyway, you would be able to access all beans by name, with no need of ApplicationContext, depending on what you need to do.

**.**

If you set property *exposeContextBeansAsAttributes* of *InternalResourceViewResolver* to *true*, you would be able to access from JSP using EL: ${applicationContext}. Depending of what you're trying to do, this can be more or less suitable.

**EDIT**: Your view resolver for JSP must be something similar to:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="exposeContextBeansAsAttributes" value="true" />
</bean>
```

The best thing is that you can get the bean you want by its name. So, probably, you won't need ApplicationContext there.

Comment: Already tried this,but it wont work for me.it is saying property exposeContextBeansAsAttributes not found.Can i have peice of code to check whether i am doing anything wrong.

Comment: Thanks,I tried already like above code.i am using spring-2.5.6.Is there any dependency to get this .

Comment: the newest jetty maven plugin use `<defaultsDescriptor>`.

Answer (score 3):

For Spring 4 it works well:

```
<%
ApplicationContext context = RequestContextUtils.findWebApplicationContext(request);
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, with spring-boot 2.1.5.RELEASE I am allowed to do these:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
thumbs.dir: <spring:eval expression="@environment.getProperty('thumbs.dir')"/><br>
users.file: <spring:eval expression="@environment.getProperty('users.file')"/><br>
jdbc.url: <spring:eval expression="@jdbcProperties.jdbcUrl"/><br>
<spring:eval expression="@jdbcProperties" var="jdbcProperties"/>
<c:if test="${empty jdbcProperties}">jdbcProperties is empty<br></c:if>
<c:if test="${!empty jdbcProperties}">jdbc.username: ${jdbcProperties.username}<br></c:if>
```

where @jdbcProperties is this spring bean:

```
@Bean("jdbcProperties")
public Properties stageDsProperties() throws IOException {
    return PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties("jdbc-datasource/jdbc-stage.properties");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me, hoping this helps someone else since it took me quite some time to figure out.
Building on Pavel Vlasov's answer:

```
<% ApplicationContext context = RequestContextUtils.findWebApplicationContext(request); %>
<% pageContext.setAttribute("myKey", context.getBean("myObject")); %>
```

And then further down my JSP page I have

```
<body>
  <div>
    <% 
       MyObject coolObject = (MyObject)pageContext.getAttribute("myKey");
       coolObject.doSomething();
    %>
  </div>
</body>
```